# check if jquery cookie array exists

Tags: jquery, cookies

I was wondering if it was possible whether jquery can check if a cookie array exists or not.

My cookie name is 'report' and with php I echo it out like this:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_COOKIE['report'][146]); echo '</pre>';
```

Which spits out something like this:

```
Array
(
    [15128] => 15128
    [13670] => 13670
)
```

This is where I'm hoping to get jquery to check if the above cookie array exists (or not), this is what I've got so far, but it's not picking up the cookie array..

```
if ( $.cookie('report[146]') ) {
  window.location = 'http://www.myurl.com/';
} else {
  alert('Please make a selection.');
}
```

My form doesn't refresh when someone ticks a checkbox, but it uses jquery to add the cookie (which works fine), but I can't seem to get jquery to check if there are any cookies.

This is the code where it adds individual cookies to the array:

```
if ($(this).attr('checked')) { 
  $.cookie('report[146]['+thisID+']', thisID, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
} else {
  $.cookie('report[146]['+thisID+']', thisID, { expires: -1, path: '/' });
};
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing right now is setting cookie that is named `report[146]['+thisID+']` (if for example thisID = `135`, then cookie name is `report[146][135]`). Value of the cookie is not an array, the value of that cookie is value of `thisID`.

If you want cookie to have name `report` and it's value should be array that at index 146 has value `thisID`, do the following:

```
var cookieValue = [];
cookieValue[146] = thisID;
```

set it:

```
$.cookie('report', cookieValue);
```

Cookie value will now be set to (that's the way array is serialized):

```
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,135
```

To read it:

```
var cookie = $.cookie('report');
if(cookie){
  var cookieValue = cookie.split(','); //you need to do this since array is serialized as comma separated values.
  var valueAtIndex146 = cookieValue[146];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, will redo the way my cookies are setup :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if($.cookie('report') == null) { 
    alert('no cookie!');
}
```

Comment: It comes up as null even though I've made a selection. If I refresh the page my cookie is stored, but I'm trying to get jquery to check for a cookie array without refreshing the page.